# Show data in label

Tags: c#, database, combobox

I have a form like this

[image: MyForm]

And i have a class `Connect` to connect to the database

```
class Connect
{
    SqlConnection con;
    public Connect()
    {
        String connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public DataTable executeSelect(String query)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        return dt;
    }

    public void execute(String query)
    {

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I have `MsProduct`table in databsae that always have new data. The `ComboBox` show my items' name. My problems is I want my form to show its Product ID in `Label` `ProductID Value`when i choose selected item in `ComboBox`. And the data is the same with the data in database For example, I select Batman book in combo box, the label will show its Product ID and the ID must be the same in database. Could you please give me the example of code to solve this problem?? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's pretty simple. You only need to setup your `ComboBox` properly.

(Updated code to meet additional requirement from comment)

```
Connect connect    = new Connect();
DataTable products = connect.executeSelect(GET_PRODUCTS_TABLE_QUERY);

productComboBox.DataSource    = products;
productComboBox.DisplayMember = "productName";
//removed setting of ValueMember so we can access the whole DataTableRow
//productComboBox.ValueMember   = "productID";
```

now your `ComboBox` has all your products with their names and IDs. Now you only need to pass the productID of the selected product to your label.
To do this you need to handle the `SelectedValueChanged` event of your `ComboBox`:

```
private void productComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //productIdLabel.Text = productComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
    DataRowView selectedRow = comboBox1.SelectedValue as DataRowView;

    if (selectedRow != null)
    {
        productIdLabel.Text    = selectedRow["productID"].ToString();
        productPriceLabel.Text = selectedRow["productPrice"].ToString();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But i have one question. How is the code if i want to add additional data to show in label(e.g, labelPrice and labelStatus)???

Answer (score 0):

If it goes about one value you can use this.

```
    private object readScalarFromDatabase(String query) //return object at first column and row
    {
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
        return myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    public static string GetTotalLinksAlias(Parameter par)
    {
        return @"
            select count(1)
            from alias_parameter_parameter
            where id_parameter = " + par.Id + @"
            ;
        ";
    }

    public int GetTotalLinksParameterWithParameterAliases(Parameter par)
    {
        openConnection();
        int totalLinks = (int)readScalarFromDatabase(QueryGenerator.GetTotalLinksParameterAlias(par));
        closeConnection();
        return totalLinks;
    }
```

then you have your int value or string and you can update you label value. It is not as your example but you will get the idea.